# Litz versus aluminium tube

Tags: power, induction, skin-effect

For a multi-kW inductive power transmission application, rather than Litz cabvling I should like to consider Aluminium tubing, to take advantage of the structural possibilities. What would be the relative efficiency?

Comment: Aluminium has a lower conductivity. Seeing as you were using Litz, I asume you are dealing with high frequencies. Impedances and reflections will also become significant

Comment: Use a coax tubing. Have seen this type for dielectric heating machine. Also I have seen special twisted pair cable for induction heating 30kW. It's kind of multi stranded  wire with aluminium foil shield.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen photos of MegaWatt electric furnaces (steel processing) fed the 60Hz power with 40 cables, each 2inch diameter and of flexible wired, arranged in 3 foot ring. In retrospect, the spacings were respecting the 8mm skindepth at 60Hz.

What caught my eye was the 3 foot ring of support, to hold the cables apart, either for heat removal! or for skin-depth minimization.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I don't know your Currents (you only specify power), but the significantly lower conductivity of Aluminium compared to copper would probably already make it a bad choice at DC.

Now, the problem litz wire is designed to solve is that due to the skin effect, only a small piece on the surface of a conductor actually conducts current – and the lower the conductivity of the conductor is, the more that becomes a problem. And the fewer individual strands you have, the lesser outer surface you get.

Things get worse, the higher your frequency becomes.

So, no, don't.